# Can't get HTTP Post to work

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to make a simple http post using the apache http client, and I can't for the life of me get it to work. I'm basing this off of the example at: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpState.html . The reason I don't think it's a problem with my url, host, or port is because I got them all to work in regular html forms and also in telnet.

The error I get is:

> org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: The server somehost.something.com failed to respond with a valid HTTP response

Here is my code:

```
public InputStream trialPost() {
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("https://somesite.com/example.php");
    NameValuePair[] data = {
      new NameValuePair("parameter1", "blah"),
      new NameValuePair("parameter2", "blah")
    };
    post.setRequestBody(data);
    HttpState hs = new HttpState();
    HttpConnection hc = new HttpConnection("somehost.something.com", 443);
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        hc.open();
        post.execute(hs, hc);    
        in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
        hc.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // handle response.
    return in;

}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Error message? Timeout? Hangs?

Comment: I just edited my question with the error message.

Comment: While I'm not an expert in this field, my guess is that you're doing an HTTP Post but your URL is HTTPS. And that's why the server "failed to respond with a valid HTTP response" because it was an HTTPS response.

Comment: You are not receiving a valid `HEADER` response.  Are you sure you are even reaching the intended page?

Comment: @unexpected Do I need to add somewhere that I didn't already that it's https? I used port # 443, and the url in question has https in it. Not sure if I need to include it somewhere else also.

Comment: @Zak I can reach my page by using a basic html form with form action leading to the url, entering in the parameters, and hitting submit.

Comment: @unexpected62 ...  He is setting the `HttpConnection` to `443` which is `ssl` or `https` ..  That portion appears to be correct

Comment: @Zak Ah, I didn't see that. I've only done something like an `HTTPSUrlConnection` so that's what I expected to see.

Comment: What are you doing that isn't supported by `java.net.HttpURLConnection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use an [`HttpConnection`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnection.html) on a server using HTTPS which won't work.  I suggest you take a look at the HTTPClient docs on [communicating over SSL](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html).

Comment: This sounds promising...trying to implement your solution now.

Comment: With that said, also consider that the host must allow external posting via SSL.  Some hosts may consider this a security issue.